# How to add number of row and auto increment on Dynamic Report?

Tags: dynamic-reports

I want to add auto increment number on dynamic report, i have 4 column 
No, Name, Address and Phone how to create auto increment on number like page_count from jasper report

Answer (score 1):

`$V{ROW_COUNT}` is the variable used to count number of rows just like we user ResultSet.getRow() in java.